# Let $K$ be a field. Prove that $K(X,Y)$ is a finite extension of $K(X^2,Y^2)$ and find its degree.

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields, extension-field

I conjectured that $K(X,Y)=K(X^2,Y^2)[X,Y]$ but to prove that I need to show $K(X,Y)\subset K(X^2,Y^2)[X,Y]$. I'm having problems showing any element in $K(X,Y)$ is of the form $X^mY^nF$ where $F\in K(X^2,Y^2)$ and $m,n$ nonnegative integers with no luck.

Comment: Do you know how to show that $K(X) = K(X^2)[X]$? (Hint: $X$ is the root of a quadratic polynomial with coefficients in $K(X^2)$...)

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Yes! But I've been trying to do the same, i.e., showing mutual containment... But you just gave me the idea to show that $K(X^2)[T]/(T^2-X^2)$ is isomorphic to $K(X)$. Right?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan But that doesn't mean the degree of the original problem is $4$, does it?...

Comment: Actually it does!